# Using LINQ to Entities and Returning a list of Guids

Tags: c#, linq

I am in the process of updating some of the old code base. In this problem I am working with a many to many relationship Questions * --- * References I do not need the whole reference object, but rather just a list of the reference ids that are attached to this question.

The currently working code is as follows

```
var questionReferences = Repo.Questions.Find(questionId).References.ToList();
var refQuestionIds = new List<Guid>();
foreach (var qr in questionReferences)
{
   refQuestionIds.Add(qr.Id);
}
```

My refactoring looks like this

```
var referenceQuestionIds = (from r in Repo.Questions.Find(questionId).References
                            select r.Id).ToList();
```

I would expect that refQuestionIds and referenceQuestionIds would both contain the exact same list of ids but in every test case referenceQuestionIds ends up null.

What is the problem with the linq statement?

[image]

Comment: What is `Repo` in this case? Are you using LINQ to Objects, LINQ to SQL, etc?

Comment: Sorry Repo is EntityFramework

Comment: `Enumerable.ToList()` *never* returns `null`, so I suspect there's something very strange going on - either misdiagnosis, or you're using a very odd LINQ provider.

Comment: What is References? What if you update the code in your refactoring to be `from r in Repo.Questions.Find(questionId).References.ToList()` ?

Comment: References is an entity collection off of question, with you change referenceQuestionIds is still null.

Comment: My bad Tim I updated the question

Comment: If you remove the ToList() due you get an IEnumerable? Your break point has been set after this line, right?

Comment: Yes it is set after this line, I will update with a better picture, just a sec.

Comment: this is weird...Maybe your call is to some other ToList() extension, not the one from System.Linq? What database are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL full. I will check to see if another ToList() is at play, did not think of that. Oh and if I take the ToList() off it is an IEnumerable

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, I meant to ask if it was null when you removed the ToList(). It should be IEnumerable, and also not null, otherwise you'd be getting an ArgumentNullException on the ToList() call.

Comment: When I remove the ToList() it is not null, it is a IEnumerable.

Comment: When enumerated, does it contain what you'd expect?

Comment: Yes, it does have the correct values... must be accessing the wrong ToList() im looking through my references as we speak.

Comment: Does this work? `System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(Repo.Questions.Find(questionId).References.Select(r => r.Id));`

Comment: Well that's just strange. VS says that its null, we know it cant be, and I can now explore that "null" object. It has non public memebers of )defaultCapacity 4 and _emptyArray {System.Guid[0]}.